# Insert two new rows with unique IDs and Values for each Department in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a number of departments, each of which have multiple staff members in them. For each of the departments, I need to add two extra staff members (Vacancy Positions).

I know I could manually type in:

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES(value1,value2,...)
```

But i was wondering if there is code that might be able to iterate through each department, and for each add in two vacancy rows.

An example of how my data might look is:

[image]

So for each of those departments, I would need an extra two vacancy positions.

To make it even more complicated, they would need 8 digit unique ID numbers that would increase by 1 for each new person; something like 00000001, 00000002, 00000003 and so on, despite being in different departments. This means that they can't be confused with any actual staff, but that they have an ID, which is required being able to edit that person in my front end system (powerapps)

Is this something that is possible, or should i just create a number of different INSERT INTO queries?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) The logic for the ids is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert . . . select`.  Something like this:

```
insert into t(year, department, staffname, . . )
    select distinct 2020, department, 'newstaff_1', 
           format(row_number() over (order by department), '00000000') as id, . . . 
    from t
    union all
    select distinct 2020, department, 'newstaff_2',
           format(row_number() over (order by department), '00000000') as id, . . . 
    from t;
```

I'm not sure what the `id` is supposed to be, but the above seems to fit into what you describe.

This uses SQL Server syntax for constructing an 8-character number.

Comment: Thank you for that @Gordon. I've plugged that in, but it seems to have created a vacancy entry for every person already in the list. It handled the IDs perfectly, and did it for each department, but I've ended up with over 3000, while i only need about 18 of them :/ This in a test table by the way, so no massive worries!

Comment: Actually, I managed to correct this by using a GROUP BY to group the entries under departments.